# failed to copy 'Wire1.nmconnection' to '/persist/NetworkManager/system-connections/': remote secure_mkdirs failed: read-only file system

Tags: adb

I tried ./adb push'Wire1.nmconnection' /persist/NetworkManager/system-connections/ to send this file to a device and it is showing something like that.

What I assume is, I don't see the device listed on my laptop.
when I did ./adb devices

it only shows emulator-5554 device

I know that emulators use pair of sequential ports, even numbered for console and odd for adb connections.

what to do now?

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to do? The adb push command is so weird that I don't understand what the command should do in the end.

Comment: Hello Robert, the command is supposed to transfer wire1.nmconnection to a device(not mobile phone)

Comment: The persist folder is by default read-only and requires admin permission to access. So you would need the remount it to r/w and change adb to root mode `adb root` (not sure if this works on emulator).

Comment: I think persist is a storage which I don't know how to access. I change adb to root mode and tried to remount the persist which is a failure.